# Adblock plus preventing stack exchange websites to load

Tags: firefox, adblock

When Adblock Plus is activated, stackoverflow, superuser, crypto exchange, etc, are loading as follows:

[image: Crypto Exchange not loaded correctly.]

But all the other sites seem to work normally.

And when I disable it, everything works fine.

I am using Firefox Quantum (61.0.1 - 64-bit) over Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS.

Do you know what is happing?

Comment: It looks like it may be blocking StackExchange's CDN. What happens when you visit https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/superuser/primary-unified.css?v=959019314e4c ?

Comment: I get the raw CSS file in both cases (Adblock activated or not).

Comment: FWIW, I use ABP on Ubuntu 16.04 and have no problems.

Comment: @davidgo Yeah, until yesterday I had no problem as well. But suddenly this started happing.

Comment: Have you tried flushing all your caches?

Comment: @davidgo Yes. I cleaned all the history, caches, etc. But it is still happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was caused by [EasyList](https://easylist.to/) unintentionally adding a blocking rule that was too broad (see [this change](https://github.com/easylist/easylist/commit/41eb1d2456a7f23fd8331ff9962f20686c4fa0bf)). It has been fixed soon after (see [this change](https://github.com/easylist/easylist/commit/35f9fe36d43153de4024547657c043452ff64895)) but the rules are only being updated once per day. After a day you should automatically receive the fix but until then you can manually update EasyList and your other filter lists in the settings of your ad blocking program.

In the Adblock Plus extension you can find an "Update all filter lists" button for that in the "Advanced" section of its settings page.

Comment: Thank you! I had imagined that it was some bug of Adblock... Now it is working normally.